# References numbering aligned along with description

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%-> For bibliography
\usepackage[numbers, super, sort&compress]{natbib}
%-> Remove square brackets from list of References
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1}
%-> Generate dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

And here, in this paragraph, I need to cite someone~\cite{ClrT10ca}. This reference will appear in the bibliography area below.

\lipsum[3]



\bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

with bib file content:

```
@article{ClrT10ca,
    author = {Tracey M. Clarke and James R. Durrant},
    title = {Charge Photogeneration in Organic Solar Cells},
    journal = {Chemical Reviews},
    volume = {110},
    number = {11},
    pages = {6736-6767},
    year = {2010}    }
```

**My question is:** *how to change the bibliography entries to be displayed according to the following image?*

[image]

Notes: the blue dotted lines show the undesired left horizontal spacing from first line and its followings. I would like to manage boldface instead of italicized.

**Obs:** *I searched many places on this feature and got nothing. So this is not a duplicate on those who answered to consider* `\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1\hfill}` *or similar.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `natbib` with `abntex2`. It won't do any good. For bold titles in the bibliography, check out the package options in the `abntex2cite` manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}



\begin{document}

\cite{ClrT10ca}.



\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```